# Spring data mongo db version compatibility with spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>      
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my Bean configurations

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}"/> 
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.dbname}" username="${mongo.username}" password="${mongo.password}" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"> 
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="awayLogDao" class="com.zymr.mongo.repository.AwayLogDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

When I try to run my project, I get following exceptions

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [mongo]
Offending resource: class path resource [conf/spring/ApplicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:62)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.findParserForElement(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:86)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:148)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1035)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:525)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried changing versions of spring and spring data mongodb.
I Used **spring version - 3.2.2.RELEASE** instead of 5.0.0.RELEASE and 
**spring data mongodb version - 1.2.0.RELEASE** . After using older versions, everything was working fine. But I want to use latest version of spring data mongodb as it supports aggregation operation.

I want to execute following query with spring data mongodb:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$and": [ 
                { "$eq": [ { "$year": "$date" }, 2017 ] }, 
                { "$eq": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 10 ] }
            ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] } 
    }
])
```

How can I achieve it? Which version of spring I need to use with latest spring data mongodb?

Comment: it looks like problem related to your bean configs. could you check namespaces in your xml-config? What version are you using for mongo namespace?

Comment: @VladBochenin I updated my question with more details on bean config. I hope, you were asking for the same

Comment: Have you tried use latest xsd version: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-2.0.xsd ?

Comment: @VladBochenin with spring-mongo-2.0.xsd, I am getting following error - [cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'. ]  I haven't changed anything but spring-mongo xsd version

Comment: Hey did you find solution for this?

Comment: I am getting this error while upgrading the spring data mongodb version from 1.x to 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue trying to update dependencies in a Spring Boot project. The long story short after updating version of `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb` from 1+ to 2+ I had to update XML namespace in the application context file as well `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd` -> `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-2.0.xsd`. But the namespace 2.0 has no `mongo` element, you should update the bean configuration changing `mongo:mongo` -> `mongo:mongo-client`

Answer (score 0):

You may try running the below command to check all your dependencies with your chosen spring core version via mvn

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Another way of doing it is to define your spring data mongodb dependency at the last of the dependency tree in your pom

Answer (score 0):

I have recently updated spring and MongoDB and it is working fine. I am using below dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is my database-connection.xml. You need to add mongoConverter in mongoTemplate after upgrading.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.10.2.xsd">
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}">

<mongo:client-options connect-timeout="${db.connectTimeout}"
        connections-per-host="${db.connectionPerHost}"
        threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="${db.threadsAllowedTblockForConnectionMultiplier}"/>
</mongo:mongo-client>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="${db.name}" host="${db.host}" mongo-ref="mongo" port="${db.port}" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoTypeMapper" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey"><null/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoMappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

<bean id="mappingConverter"     class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mongoMappingContext" />
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="mongoTypeMapper"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```